# Highcharts Funnel - Setting Height of Piece to a Fixed Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

The current funnel that I have right now is:

```js
$(function () {
    var dataEx = [
                ['1 Visit', 352000],
                ['2 Visits',       88000],
                ['3+ Visits',       42000]
            ],
        len = dataEx.length,
        sum = 0,
        minHeight = 0.05,
        data = [];
    
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        sum += dataEx[i][1];
    }
    
    for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
        var t = dataEx[i],
            r = t[1] / sum;
        data[i] = {
            name: t[0],
            y: ( r > minHeight ? t[1]  : sum * minHeight ),
            label: t[1]
        }
    }
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'funnel',
            marginRight: 100,
       
        
          events: {
        load: function() {
          var chart = this;
          Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
            p.dataLabel.attr({
              x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
              'text-anchor': 'middle'
            })
          })
        },
        redraw: function() {
          var chart = this;
          Highcharts.each(chart.series[0].data, function(p, i) {
            p.dataLabel.attr({
              x: (chart.plotWidth - chart.plotLeft) / 2,
              'text-anchor': 'middle'
            })
          })
        }
      },
        
       },  
      
        title: {
            text: 'Guest Return Funnel',
            x: -50
        },
        tooltip: {
            //enabled: false
            formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.key  +
                    '</b> = <b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.point.label, 0) +'</b>';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
            
            
            allowPointSelect: true,
            borderWidth: 12,
            
            animation: {
                duration: 400
            },
            
            
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    
                    connectorWidth:0,
                    distance: 0,
                    
                    formatter: function(){
                      var point = this.point;  
                        console.log(point);
                      return '<b>' + point.name + '</b> (' + Highcharts.numberFormat(point.label, 0) + ')'; 
                    },                
                    minSize: '10%',
                    color: 'black',
                    softConnector: true
                },
                
                neckWidth: '30%',
              neckHeight: '0%',
              width: '50%',
              height: '110%'
                
                
                //old options are as follows:
                
                //neckWidth: '50%',
                //neckHeight: '50%',
                //-- Other available options
                //height: '200'
                // width: pixels or percent
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Unique users',
            data: data
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

As you can see, the height of the first piece is much more than the rest. I want to make the height of all the pieces a fixed value but make the width of the pieces change according to their respective values. So the width will be changing (decreasing from top to bottom) but the height will remain the same.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please do not link to code.  Create a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data in funnel chart type can only affect to the height of the point, please take look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pdsL5uyq/

If you want to have fixed height of the pieces, you must have the same values in data. To correct the width of the elements, you can only use: **neckWidth** and **width**

You can deduce how it exactly works from Funnel source code: http://code.highcharts.com/modules/funnel.src.js

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'funnel',
    data: [10, 10, 10],
    neckWidth: 50,
    neckHeight: 0,
    width: 200,
    dataLabels: {
      format: "{point.y}"
    }
  }]
});
```

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/funnel-series